# Getting Null Pointed exception error but runs fine? Java JComboBox (DropDown box)

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, integer, jcombobox

So Integer N here is controlled by a JComboBox basically a drop down menu 1-4. My problem is that I get a nullpointerexception error when I initially set N from the box..any ideas how to fix this? I tested it  by printing out what N was in both actionlistener instances  and it's null in the first one and it's correct in the second one.

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;


public class Lab10 extends JPanel
{
  private StringBuilder string, string2, string3, string4; //loads SuperStrings faster by appending all at once
  private JRadioButton occurrence, alphabetical;
  private JPanel text;
  private JComboBox<Integer> input;
  private JLabel label, file1,file2, unique, unique2;
  private JButton load, go,go2;
  private CountLinkedList<SuperString> words, words3; //Change impliments CountList to extends BinaryCountTree
  private OrderedLinkedList<SuperString> words2, words4;//Change impliments CountList to extends BinaryCountTree
  private String filename,filename2;
  private int width = 450;
  private int height = 550;
  private TextArea textarea,textarea2;
  Scanner scan;

  public Lab10()
  {
    string = new StringBuilder();
    string2 = new StringBuilder();
    string3 = new StringBuilder();
    string4 = new StringBuilder();
    ButtonListener listener = new ButtonListener();
    Button2Listener listener2 = new Button2Listener();
    Integer [] select = {1,2,3,4};
    input = new JComboBox<Integer>(select);
    text = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1,2));
    go = new JButton("Select Text File 1: ");
    go2 = new JButton("Select Text File 2: ");
    label = new JLabel("N: " );
    unique = new JLabel("");
    unique2 = new JLabel("");
    file1 = new JLabel("");
    file1.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    unique.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    file2 = new JLabel("");
    file2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    unique2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));

    occurrence= new JRadioButton("Occurrence");
    occurrence.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_O);
    occurrence.addActionListener(listener);
    occurrence.addActionListener(listener2);
    occurrence.setSelected(true);


    alphabetical = new JRadioButton("Alphabetical");
    alphabetical.setMnemonic(KeyEvent.VK_A);
    alphabetical.addActionListener(listener);
    alphabetical.addActionListener(listener2);

    ButtonGroup group = new ButtonGroup();
    group.add(occurrence);
    group.add(alphabetical);

    go.addActionListener(listener);
    go2.addActionListener(listener2);
    input.addActionListener(listener);
    input.addActionListener(listener2);

    textarea = new TextArea("",0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    textarea2 = new TextArea("",0,0,TextArea.SCROLLBARS_VERTICAL_ONLY);
    textarea.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    textarea2.setFont(new Font("Helvetica",Font.PLAIN,24));
    textarea.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    textarea2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(width,height));
    setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,700));
    text.add(textarea);
    text.add(textarea2);
    add(occurrence);
    add(alphabetical);
    add(label);
    add(input);
    add(go);
    add(file1);
    add(unique);
    add(go2);
    add(file2);
    add(unique2);

    add(text);

    textarea.setText("No File Selected");
    textarea2.setText("No File Selected");


  }
    public class ButtonListener implements ActionListener //makes buttons do things
    {
      JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("../Text");


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
       Integer N = input.getSelectedIndex()+1;

        if(event.getSource() == go)
      {

        int returnvalue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(returnvalue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      try
      {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String text1= file.getName();
        file1.setText(text1);
        filename = file.getName();
        System.err.println(filename);
        scan = new Scanner(file);

      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.err.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        return;
      }       
    }
    else
    {
      return;
    }


     String[] storage = new String[N];
    words = new CountLinkedList<SuperString>();
    words2 = new OrderedLinkedList<SuperString>();
   for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
     storage[i] = scan.next().toLowerCase().replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
                  .replaceAll("[.,':]","");

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0;i<=N-2;i++)
        storage[i] = storage[i+1];
      storage[N-1] = scan.next().toLowerCase();
      storage[N-1] = storage[N-1].replace(",","").replace(".","").replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
                  .replaceAll("[.,':]","");
      SuperString ss = new SuperString(storage);
      SuperString ss2= new SuperString(storage);
      words.add(ss );
      words2.add(ss2 );
    }

    textarea.setText("");
        }
    SuperString[] ss = new SuperString[words.size()];
    SuperString[] ss2 = new SuperString[words2.size()];
    int i=0;
    int count =0, count2= 0;


    for(SuperString word: words)
    {
      ss[i] = word;
      i++;
    }
    int j=0;
    for(SuperString word: words2)
    {
      ss2[j] = word;
      j++;
    }


    Arrays.sort(ss, new SuperStringCountOrder());

    for(SuperString word : ss)
    {
      count++;
      string.append(Integer.toString(count)+ "       "+ word+ "\n");
    }
    if(occurrence.isSelected())
    {
     textarea.setText("");
     textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
     textarea.append(string.toString());
    }


     for(SuperString word : ss2)
    {
       count2++;
       string2.append(Integer.toString(count2)+ "       "+ word.toString()+ "\n");  
    }
         if(alphabetical.isSelected())
    {
      textarea.setText("");
      textarea.append("    "+filename+" has wordcount: "+words.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
      textarea.append(string2.toString());

    }
     unique.setText("Unique Count: "+ Integer.toString(words.size()));

      }
    }


    public class Button2Listener implements ActionListener
    {
       JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser("../Text");


      public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent event)
      {
       Integer N = input.getSelectedIndex()+1;

         if(event.getSource() == go2)
      {

        int returnvalue = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);

    if(returnvalue == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION)
    {
      try
      {
        File file = chooser.getSelectedFile();
        String text2= file.getName();
        file2.setText(text2);
        filename2 = file.getName();
        System.err.println(filename);
        scan = new Scanner(file);

      }
      catch (IOException e)
      {
        System.err.println("IO EXCEPTION");
        return;
      }       
    }
    else
    {
      return;
    }

     String[] storage = new String[N];
    words3 = new CountLinkedList<SuperString>();
    words4 = new OrderedLinkedList<SuperString>();
   for(int i=1;i<N;i++)
     storage[i] = scan.next().toLowerCase().replace(",","").replace(".","");

    while(scan.hasNext())
    {
      for(int i=0;i<=N-2;i++)
        storage[i] = storage[i+1];
      storage[N-1] = scan.next().toLowerCase();
      storage[N-1] = storage[N-1].replace(",","").replace(".","").replaceAll("[^A-Za-z0-9]", "")
                  .replaceAll("[.,':]","");
      SuperString ss = new SuperString(storage);
      SuperString ss2= new SuperString(storage);
      words3.add(ss );
      words4.add(ss2 );
    }
    textarea2.setText("");
         }
    SuperString[] sstwo = new SuperString[words3.size()];
    SuperString[] ss2two = new SuperString[words4.size()];
    int i=0;
    int count =0, count2= 0;

    for(SuperString word2: words3)
    {
      sstwo[i] = word2;
      i++;
    }

    int j=0;
    for(SuperString word2: words4)
    {
      ss2two[j] = word2;
      j++;
    }  

    Arrays.sort(sstwo, new SuperStringCountOrder());

        for(SuperString word2 : sstwo)
    {
      count++;
      string3.append(Integer.toString(count)+ "       "+ word2+ "\n");
    }
    if(occurrence.isSelected())
    {
     textarea2.setText("");
     textarea2.append("    "+filename2+" has wordcount: "+words3.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
     textarea2.append(string3.toString());
    }

     for(SuperString word2 : ss2two)
    {
       count2++;
        string4.append(count2+"   "+ "  "+word2+"\n");     
    }
     if(alphabetical.isSelected())
          {
       textarea2.setText("");
       textarea2.append("    "+filename2+" has wordcount: "+words3.size()+
      "\n-------------------------\n\n");
       textarea2.append(string4.toString());
       }

     unique2.setText("Unique Count: "+ Integer.toString(words3.size()));

      }
    }



   public static void main(String[] arg)
  {
    JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lab 10");
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
    frame.getContentPane().add(new Lab10());
    frame.pack();
    frame.setVisible(true);
  }
}
```

Comment: how do the ActionListener classes have access to the `input` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question doesn't make sense as written:

```
Integer N = input.getSelectedIndex()+1;
System.out.println(N);
```

The `println` cannot possibly tell you that `N` is `null`.

- If the expression on the RHS of the `=` executes without an exception, then `N` is guaranteed to be non-null.  The `getSelectedIndex()` call returns an `int`, and the result of the addition will be an `int`.  That will then be autoboxed to an `Integer`, and autoboxing can NEVER give you a `null`.
- If the expression on the RHS of the `=` throws an exception, then the `println` statement won't be executed.

In other words, what you are describing is **Impossible**.

---

So what I think is actually happening is one of the following:

- Your code is throwing a `NullPointerException` in the first statement because `input` is `null`, and you have *misdiagnosed* that as meaning that `N` is `null`.
- This code is sufficiently different from your actual code that it is not possible to understand what is really going on.
- You have made a mistake in the compiling / running / deploying of your code, such that you are running a stale binary.

Comment: You are correct, by null I should've said displays nothing...should I upload all of my code and just tell you which line it is?

Comment: First check to see if I've already identified the cause of your problem; i.e. that `input` is `null`.  If so, you just need to figure out *why* it is null.

Comment: Well it is initially set as 1 but when I change it from 1 to 2,3,or 4 I get the exception...

Comment: @Cpt.Awesome - That doesn't make sense.  The type of `input` is a `JComboBox` not a number.  Making a change to the content of the combo box cannot cause `input` to become `null`.  An `input` field / variable can only be `null` if either you assigned `null` to it, or you didn't initialize it in the first place.  Hint: could this be happening because you have multiple declarations for `input`???

Comment: I posted all of my code, I know it's a lot but my problem is on line 272 ..that's where I'm getting the error. N (being input) is the same for both instances.

Comment: Tell us which line is 272 (we don't have line numbers here).

Comment: SuperString[] sstwo = new SuperString[words3.size()];

Comment: Your code is so badly indented that I cannot figure out why ... but it that line throws a `NullPointerException`, it is because `word3` is `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't compilable the way it is now. You can't have multiple public classes in the same file. Also, to access the selected index from a JComboBox, this is what your actionPerformed method should look like.

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        JComboBox cb = (JComboBox)e.getSource();
        int n = cb.getSelectedIndex();
        //etc
    }
```